# Unable to get images from API to load in UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get 100 images from an API to be viewable in a Table View. I am using the following code to get the images into the cell:

```
import UIKit

class CatImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
//URL containing the image
let URL_IMAGE = URL(string: "http://example.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=100")

@IBOutlet weak var catImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        //creating a dataTask
        let getImageFromUrl = session.dataTask(with: URL_IMAGE!) { (data, response, error) in

            //if there is any error
            if let e = error {
                //displaying the message
                print("Error Occurred: \(e)")

            } else {
                //in case of now error, checking wheather the response is nil or not
                if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {

                    //checking if the response contains an image
                    if let imageData = data {

                        //getting the image
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                        //displaying the image
                        self.catImage.image = image

                    } else {
                        print("Image file is currupted")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No response from server")
                }
            }
        }

        //starting the download task
        getImageFromUrl.resume()

    }
```

}

---

I am getting the following errors:

1) Method does not override any method from its superclass
2) Value of type `UITableViewCell` has no member `viewDidLoad`

---

If you need more code, let me know what you need and I will post it.

Comment: Why are you getting the image within UITableViewCell subclass?

It is better coding this on a helper class or UIViewController.

Comment: Actually there are many issues in this code. I would suggest to use this library https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Method does not override any method from its superclass 2) Value of
>   type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'viewDidLoad'

1) This error tell you, the 'override' word 'overrides' method from a parent Class.

2) UITableViewCell is not a subclass from UIViewController, viewDidLoad is a method from UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

1) Method does not override any method from its superclass 2) Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'viewDidLoad'

This line because  you calling viewDidLoad method in UITableViewCell class , so remove

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}`

in UITableViewCell class and write in UIViewController class

Answer (score 0):

change **viewDidLoad** with **awakeFromNib**